# Automated reporting from Snowflake - No BI

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are currently using Snowflake and Power BI for dashboarding. These two together have been working well for us but we lack the ability to create automated reports for larger file exports

I need to schedule automated reports that save a csv/excel file of ~500K rows (Power BI limits at 150k) into a shared location (preferable OneDrive)

Every solution I look into is trying to sell you on their BI solution or other features that we do not need. I just need a low-cost solution to export data from Snowflake. I looked into SSRS by creating a linked server but ran into issues with UTF-8 and thought there has to be an easier solution.

Any ideas/recommendations?

Comment: Just a question, but why are you exporting data from Snowflake and then reading it in to Power BI rather than directly querying Snowflake from Power BI?

Comment: Sorry, that was a confusing way to explain my situation. I am not importing this data into Power BI. I need this data set in a csv/excel file for users to be able to access. Since the data set is so large, they cannot export out of BI. I need to set up scheduled reports from Snowflake that users can access.

Comment: Ok, makes sense  Just follow Rob's answer: use a task to copy the data into an internal or external stage and then use the technology of your choice to move this data to your preferred file location

Answer (score 1):

Could you export the data to Azure Blob Storage and have Power BI read the export file from there?

Assuming that is possible, you can create a task in Snowflake that exports data every n minutes/hours/day, etc and writes the result set you are looking for to Azure Blob.

```
create task export_to_blob
    warehouse = task_wh
    schedule = '60 minute'
as
copy into @azure_blob from sales.public.nation file_format = (type = csv);
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html